# Internal 2TB SSD suddenly inaccessible except through cmd as administrative user

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, windows-8.1

I've been using the boot drive `SSD` from a Windows 8.1 computer as an *internal*, `SATA`-connected secondary drive in Windows 10 machine for months. And still often switching it back to the Windows 8.1 machine to boot it up.

I never changed ACL to access it on Windows 10, never had problems booting on Windows 8.1. But now, cannot boot into Windows 8.1 on old machine, and getting "Access is denied" error on Windows 10.

[image: Windows 10 - Access is denied]

I tried running `Windows Explorer` as `administrator` - does not help.

**But I know the disk is not dead!**

Running `cmd` as `administrator` does allow me to traverse the filesystem, and copy files out to another disk!

(Also, this is perhaps irrelevant, but it is a Samsung EVO, supposedly a very high quality drive, and only 3 years old. Obviously anything can happen but this would be very unusual, to fail so soon.)

---

### Background

Before the disk became inaccessible on Windows 10, and refused to boot up windows 8.1, it became partially inaccessible. One particular folder refused to open in Windows Explorer on Windows 10, and was supposedly corrupted.

[image: Error message accessing folder in Documents]

But I can access that folder and its contents even now on Windows 10 using `cmd` as `administrator`, and I see no corruption.

I had no problem accessing any other folder I tried on that disk at that time.

I decided to boot it up in the old machine, as the boot drive, and run chkdsk. Lo and behold, chkdsk ran automatically on startup. Then I got a black screen. I restarted several times and got black screen, or a brief loading animation before another black screen. **It seems that somehow, permissions changed on the disk, or some corruption made it seem as if they had.**

After this, the entire SSD became inaccessible on the Windows 10 machine.

[This how-to suggests](https://www.easeus.com/storage-media-recovery/fix-drive-is-not-accessible.html) changing the owner. I *started* that process, but canceled it very quickly (perhaps affecting a few hundred files) because it changes owner file-by-file, which would take hours. I thought it would change whole-disk permissions instantly. *So it doesn't seem possible* that the problem with the disk would be ***permissions***, since it stopped working very quickly.

Any ideas on how to recover this disk would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Does it _still_ say "Corrupted and unreadable"? If so, then it's not exactly a problem with permissions or ownership. And yes, disks (and other hardware) _do_ stop working suddenly for various reasons.

Comment: @user1686 I can traverse the file system in ‘cmd’ as administrator. I was able to copy an image (the screenshot I attached here, in fact), from the disk to my desktop. But when I try to access the disk in explorer now, I get a permissions error rather than “corrupted” error.

Comment: @user1686 to me it was a bit surprising that I could plug in my boot disk from my old machine into a new machine and immediately access its file system without needing my old machine’s password. But I guess that’s windows security for you

Comment: It shouldn’t have been possible. But your expectation of needing your old password is also incorrect. You should have been denied access until you changed the ACL on the protected folder. You don’t specify where exactly this file was located on the drive. There is nothing wrong with Windows security. It sounds like the drive has seen better days, changing the ownership of the files, most definitely was a destructive action if you wanted to boot to the drive from the drives machine

Comment: @Ramhound There was no protected folder.  Perhaps Windows 8.1 boot drives do not have ACL like windows 10 does? My 8.1 machine booted up with no problems for months, while I was also able to use its boot drive as an internal, SATA-connected drive in the windows 10 machine as well. Are you saying that should not have been possible?

Comment: I've reorganized the question. I know it's wordy. Hopefully clearer now. The drive seems to be functioning. I can access it through cmd as administrator. I just can't access it through all the normal methods like Explorer, and other programs cannot access it, which is a big problem because most of my `vagrant` VMs are on there, as well as a lot of coding-related stuff.

Comment: There are always protected folders. For instance Program Files is a protected folder from unprivileged users. While a user’s profile directory is protected from other users on the machine and including users from a second machine.  While WindowsApps by default can’t be viewed by any user unless you change it, which on Windows 8.1, breaks any application installed from the Windows Store (I forget what it’s called on Windows 8.1)

Comment: “Are you saying that should not have been possible?” - Impossible to day without knowing where on the drive you had these VMs. Changing the ownership of the files that contains the files you want is your best option.  However, if the drive is failing, that process might start and hang up on whatever area of the disk has a problem.  That could cause more problems, but your issue with viewing the drive in File Explorer must certainly is the permissions of the folders.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand that some folders are privileged, but I'm not talking about those. I can't access the disk *at all*, **except** as Administrator from `cmd`. And the folder that originally stopped working was not a protected folder. I had just saved a bunch of Word documents there! And I have since been able to use `cmd` to copy them out to the Windows 10 desktop.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't see how my VMs are relevant at all to my inability to access a physical, real SSD that I have inserted into my physical, real Windows 10 machine. I only mentioned VMs in a later comment to say that the disk is kind of important. As I said, I've been using the disk daily, including the VMs. The disk is not accessible, that's my problem I'm hoping to solve :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135058/discussion-between-buttle-butkus-and-ramhound).

Comment: There's only two reasons I know of that could cause this, user lacks ACL permissions to the root of the partition [`I:`] or the partition has been locked/hidden to all but the `Administrators` group _(I'm unsure how to do this natively, as I've only come across this options in Yamicsoft's Windows < 8||10> Manager)_. Since `I:` contains a Windows install, was that specific install hibernated or fully shutdown?

Comment: @JW0914 The Windows 8.1 machine had was fully shut down before I removed the SSD and inserted it into the Windows 10 machine and noticed the first issue ( one particular folder was inaccessible "the file or directory is corrupted and unreadable"). I decided I would run `chkdsk` on the 8.1 machine, so I moved the SSD back there, started it up, and `chkds`k ran on its own at boot time. But Windows never loaded. The screen was black. I left it for a couple of minutes before **hard shutdown**. I wonder if the hard shutdown did something. I've never hibernated.